# Create HTML table choice item displaying code in the table output

Tags: html, microsoft-flow, table

My HTML table which I created in a workflow in Flow.microsoft.com is working perfectly fine but when I enter the choice items it outputs a code in the file. for example for: -
coloumn: 
Change Outcome

choices: 
Success
Open
Cancelled
Rescheduled
Issue
Chosen value: Open

The output instead of a single chosen value it gives like this:
{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":1,"Value":"Open"}

But for the normal column fields the output is normal.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Are your columns set to "Automatic", or "Custom"?

Comment: It you are already using "Custom" column definitions, you should be able to reference `item()["Change Outcome"]["Value"]` instead of referencing `item()["Change Outcome"]`.  If you are trying to stick with Automatic columns, that will be a bit trickier.

Comment: I am using custom columns, Willman. However exactly with your method it says "The expression is invalid".

Comment: Sorry, my fault, need to use single quotes:  `item()['Change Outcome']['Value']`

Comment: Hi Willman, It worked perfectly this time. Thank you very much man.

Comment: Can you add it as an answer, so that I can mark it as answered for help of if somebody else needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recapping our discussion:  If you are using the Advanced -> Column Options -> Custom, your can set the expression for that item to point to the `Value` in the JSON sub-object rather than directly at the column object.  For a choice column named `Change Outcome`, that expression would look like:

```
item()['Change Outcome']['Value']
```

User fields are a similar case of having a subject with multiple values, but the properties are different.  A User field from SharePoint will look like this in your results:

```
"User1": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
    "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|thisuser@thistenant.com",
    "DisplayName": "Somebody Whologgedin",
    "Email": "thisuser@thistenant.com",
    "Picture": "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mytestsite/_layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=thisuser@thistenant.com",
    "Department": "Human Resources",
    "JobTitle": "Learning and Development Specialist"
  }
```

So, if you wanted to just show the user's email in your table, you would reference:

```
item()['MyUserField']['Email']
```

Comment: There's an additional question about the problem I'm just facing is with the field of username where user selects the User from the Azure AD that field is neither working with the first or second method and gives the error that this field doesn't exist. Any solution for this bro?

Comment: I added info about User columns to the answer.  Note, once your workflow has run at least once, you can always go into the history instance and review the body output of most actions to figure out what the JSON structure of its data is.  It is a shame this is documented better, but at least the run history gives us a way to figure it out.

Comment: Hi Willman, Thanks for updating and the answer. I appreciate it. 
But I have tried these ways my actual statement is:
item()['Change_x0020_Originator']['DisplayName']

Change_x0020_Originator is the field value and I have tried it various ways and the way you have said this way as well but I don't know why it gives this error:
The execution of template action 'Create_HTML_table' failed. The column values could not be evaluated: 'The template language expression 'item()['Change_x0020_Originator']['DisplayName']' cannot be evaluated because property 'Change_x0020_Originator 'doesn't exist

Comment: I assume you are getting values from a filtered array or a Get Items action -- in the flow run history, take a look at the output body from that action to confirm that the JSON has the `Change_x0020_Originator`, it may not be named in the JSON what you think it is.

Comment: that JSON looks good for what your are trying to do.  This may just be a cut /paste mistake, but your error message appear to have an extra space `'Change_x0020_Originator '` -- if you accidentally included an extra space inside the single quote after the word Originator, that would cause it to fail.

Comment: "Change_x0020_Originator": {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
      "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|r.hardy@leeds.ac.uk",
      "DisplayName": "Robert Hardy (r.hardy)",
      "Email": "r.hardy@leeds.ac.uk",
      "Picture": "https://leeds.sharepoint.com/sites/webforms/_layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=r.hardy@leeds.ac.uk",
      "Department": "Innovation & Technology Services",
      "JobTitle": "Application Analyst"
    },
    "Change_x0020_Originator#Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|r.hardy@leeds.ac.uk",

Comment: Hi @Willman this is the output I get from the filter array of which output I use in table as body. Can you please have a look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this still looks like you should be able to successfully get the value in your table with `item()['Change_x0020_Originator']['DisplayName']`.  As mentioned in the previous comment, double check your column expression to make sure you didn't accidentally put an extra space in there.

Comment: Hi @Willman you are absolutely right, It should work. I have tried this again by making sure everything is correct but it gives the following error again
'The template language expression 'item()['Change_x0020_Originator']['DisplayName']' cannot be evaluated because property 'Change_x0020_Originator' doesn't exist, available properties are '@odata.etag, ItemInternalId, ID, Title, Request_x0020_Name, Date_x003a_, ChangeType, ChangeType#Id, Summary, ReasonforChange_x0028_includeeme, DetailsDescription_x003a__x0028_, CAB_x0020_Notes, CAB_x0020_Advisory_x0020_to_x002,

Comment: It gives all the other properties except the ones linked to the Azure AD that's the issue. Don't know why it's behaving very weird but can't get ahead through this.

Comment: You are absolutely right and correct. It should work 100% but it's behaving very abnormally by not allowing me to use  the Azure AD fields.

Comment: I think we need more eyes on this, I would say post a new question specific to this column problem.  Post the JSON that you included in the comments here, the expression you are using and the full error message (the comment is cutting off the rest of the "available properties are ...", but you could include the whole thing in a question post).

Comment: Hi man,

Thanks once again for all your help. It means a lot to me. As you have said, I have posted a new question regarding this issue. I am hopeful to get this problem sorted.